# Content Search Web Part - Query String

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, content-search-web-part, query-string

I would like to filter CSWP results based on query string.

I have CSWP in a page `ItemDetail.aspx`, the query is

```
Path:"http://sp03:2016/Lists/Announcement%20Custom/" contentclass="STS_ListItem_Announcements",
```

which is displaying all the items of the "Announcement Custom" list, like

```
sp03:2016/Lists/DispForm.aspx?ID=3
sp03:2016/Lists/DispForm.aspx?ID=2
sp03:2016/Lists/DispForm.aspx?ID=1
```

I would like to display only one item with filter by ID. I have tried to use `ID={QueryString.ID}` at the end but it does not work

So if my url is `ItemDetail.aspx?Id=2`, this should be passed to the filter and the page should display only one result: `sp03:2016/Lists/DispForm.aspx?ID=2`

Comment: Path:"http://sp03:2016/Lists/Announcement%20Custom/" contentclass="STS_ListItem_Announcements" {?ID={QueryString.ID}} even this did not help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Path:"sp03:2016/Lists/Announcement%20Custom/" 
contentclass="STS_ListItem_Announcements" 
ListItemID:{QueryString.ID}
```

Add after your page url this `#k=?ID=1`

So you have this

```
http://YOURSITE/Pages/test.aspx#k=?ID=1
```

or without `#k=`

```
http://YOURSITE/Pages/test.aspx?ID=1
```

Comment: Thanks this is working great, even without #k is also working fine (http://YOURSITE/Pages/test.aspx?ID=1